# Is the usage of text embedded in an image a bad practice, for very controlled uses?

Tags: website-design, usability, interaction-design

What are your thoughts on writing your text in images?

I'm not saying throughout the whole website... But in certain key locations like image carousels. And I'm not talking about the special cases where you have font types that browsers can't render. I'm talking about text that uses standard fonts and is not too big (3/4 bullets).

Should I embed the text in the images that compose the carousel? Or should I apply the text to the images as "real text" HTML?

What are the advantages/ disadvantages of using text in an image?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Well, just off the top of my head (and some new ones added in based on comments against this post)...

**Cons**

- Text can't scale, so it doesn't get adjusted alongside standard browser font-scaling options
- No SEO benefit - search engines don't read images so they'll ignore any text in images.
- Screenreaders won't read it out so it'll only be of any use to sighted users. (Well, with some Alt text you may get that announced, but it'll be as descriptive text, not as actual paragraph / header text)
- Images aren't vectors (unlike text) so when zooming / pinch-to-zoom the text will become distorted. This wouldn't happen if it was actual text.
- 'Retina' browsers will not show text images as clearly as non-retina devices.
- Images are larger than text, so it's an increase in page load time and server requests.
- Page translators (such as Google Translate) won't be able to translate image text, and future localization / internationalisation will be made harder because of this.
- Saving the page to off-line browsers (such as Pocket) may ignore the image text altogether.
- Content won't be recognised in internal search, so people searching your website for terms mentioned in image text won't get found on the results page
- Maintainability - If you need to make changes to text, you just change the text! You cannot change text inside an image unless you have the original file that the image was created with as well as the program that created it. So if the image was created in Photoshop, you would need the original Photoshop file as well as the Photoshop application to change the text.
- Users will be unable to copy and paste from an image.

**Pros**

- It'll keeps your designer happy (until they see it on a device that isn't the same as the one they designed it on).

Unless it's something like a company logo, then there really isn't a need to have images as text.

With techniques such as using `font-face` you can deliver the actual font to the users browser.

Using images as text *when that text actually needs to be read* is not advised and is verging on laziness really.

Comment: Never would have thought of Google Translate and Pocket. Awesome answer!

Comment: Another thing is that localization becomes a pain if you ever go for it.

Comment: @Mervin: That's true. Good point. Care to add it to your answer JonW?

Comment: Not sure about "No SEO Benefit" - doesn't it go to the alt text in an image? I've read that putting an image with alt text inside a header tag will place it semantically and give the search engine something to crawl.

Comment: @Mervin Yeah, that's kind of tied in with the translation issue, but I'll add that in too as it's probably a more common situation.

Comment: Another problem is Maintainability: _"If you need to make changes to text, you just change the text! You cannot change text inside an image unless you have the original file that the image was created with as well as the program that created it. So if the image was created in Photoshop, you would need the original Photoshop file as well as the Photoshop application to change the text."_ - [source](http://www.tbrooksconsulting.com/blog_textimage.html)

Comment: @Brendan That will depend on what the image is. For instance if it is acting as a Link then the Alt text should describe what that link is going to, rather than just replicating the text ("Our products page" for example). So yes, all images should have Alt text, but Alt text is not always being used for the same thing.

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth Great point there, totally forgot about that one, and it's a biggie!

Comment: +1 Very good list. Also, users can't copy/paste.

Comment: Personally, I loathe web sites that have their addresses in image files. How am I supposed to copy and paste into Google Maps to find out where they are?

Comment: The only case in which I would condone using images as a font is when the font you want to use (or the size in which you want to use it) doesn't render well or can't be styled as desired with css/font-face. Even then, it may be more worthwhile to re-evaluate the font/styling you're using.

Comment: @dom: You mean "I would not condone", right? :)

Comment: @JohnAssymptoth No, I mean "The only case in which I would condone..."

Comment: I'm not really into font licenses, but is it possible for a font to be legally used in an image, while it would not be in a @font-face?

Comment: @JonW As far as I know, alt tags are actually for describing images, not describing anchor urls. That's what anchor titles are for. If a search engine crawls your page, the alt tag needs to describe your image. At least, that's what I thought.

Comment: Great list, though the Retina point is slightly spurious. Websites can and should provide assets at higher resolutions for high DPI displays these days, where appropriate.

Comment: @scottishwildcat yes totally agree, but that is yet another overhead in assets, maintenance etc. As with most of the items in my list there's various workaround to put in place to make things more optimal but the point is that they're all *workarounds* that end up giving *almost* the same benefits to using text. But you're not going to get the ideal solution without actually using text. It's text, that is what text is for; writing text. You'll end up burning more time & resources faking images to look like text while trying to get the same benefits as text as you would if you did it properly.

Comment: Another problem is: Users that have special contrast needs can’t simply overwrite the background/text color of the image. The same goes for fonts, as some fonts might be hard to read for certain users. They typically overwrite it, but this doesn’t work for images, of course.

Comment: Also related to the previous comment is Dark Mode, which is a problem with this type of images as text.

Answer (score 1):

That might be a good but ancient solution to add text to images to prevent users from copying data. You can prevent copying on sites altogether nowadays/ also you can make elements non selectable.

One other key thing to note, that by using text in images, eventually you are adding more work to change any element. I might sound as a supporter of angular.js but by using it, one can just dynamically achieve the same effect, by two way data binding, and this creates a better experience for the user!

Answer (score 1):

Jakob Nielsen in his books "Eyetracking Web Usability," recommends against placing text on top of images or textured background in advertisements because only 35% of people will look at it.